# Microsoft Graph (Delta) - No longer included?

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the Microsoft Graph API which includes a delta function for file changes. I believe this has now stopped working in both v1.0 & beta versions.

The delta function is explained in https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_delta

When executed using 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/delta'

The response is:

```
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Delta sync is not supported for 'v1.0' version.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "768dc419-fc00-4318-8dc4-827af8dba625",
        "date": "2016-10-26T21:52:43"
    }
}
```

}

Any ideas? Is the API broken? Functionality removed?  Help please :-)

Comment: Microsoft - Please help - something is broken!!

Comment: Any advise on this would be appreciated???!

Answer (score 4):

I believe this was fixed on 30th October. Please retry and it should work. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: I'm no longer able to reproduce this issue. If you're still running into this problem, please leave a comment here so we can investigate.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this issue/problem.

It stopped working in the last few days.

You can test this using the [Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer).

None of the **documented** endpoints are currently working:

- GET /me/drive/root/delta
- GET /drives/{drive-id}/root/delta
- GET /users/{user_id}/drive/root/delta

There was no notification from Microsoft stating this functionality's depreciation, nor has this functionality been removed from documentation.

Answer (score 1):

We've also experienced this issue and the application we are developing relies heavily on delta endpoints, which worked fine for a couple of months!

Delta endpoints stopped working for all the Tenants using our application. I also confirm that they do not work in Graph explorer.

Our clients are getting very disappointed now. Can any Microsoft developer confirm that this bug is known and is being fixed now?